# Python: I keep getting a broadcasting error, but I'm not sure how to fix it

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, gradient

I am attempting to adapt the accepted answer code from this link for my purpose:
[Plot gradient arrows over heatmap with plt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201364/plot-gradient-arrows-over-heatmap-with-plt)

I am working on a project that requires me to take a thermal image in the form of a .csv file and then take the data from the .csv file to make arrows (via quiverplot streamplot etc.) that show the direction of the heat flow from the hottest point (highest pixel value) on the image. I think that this could be achieved using the gradient of the image but I am unsure how to implement that.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

directory = os.chdir(r'user_directory') #Set folder to look in
file = 'data.csv'
data = np.genfromtxt(file, delimiter = ',')

horizontal_min, horizontal_max, horizontal_stepsize = 0, 100, 0.3
vertical_min, vertical_max, vertical_stepsize = 0, 100, 0.5

horizontal_dist = horizontal_max-horizontal_min
vertical_dist = vertical_max-vertical_min

horizontal_stepsize = horizontal_dist / float(math.ceil(horizontal_dist/float(horizontal_stepsize)))
vertical_stepsize = vertical_dist / float(math.ceil(vertical_dist/float(vertical_stepsize)))

xv, yv = np.meshgrid(np.arange(horizontal_min, horizontal_max, horizontal_stepsize),
                 np.arange(vertical_min, vertical_max, vertical_stepsize))
xv+=horizontal_stepsize/2.0
yv+=vertical_stepsize/2.0

result_matrix = np.asmatrix(data)
yd, xd = np.gradient(result_matrix)

def func_to_vectorize(x, y, dx, dy, scaling=0.01):
    plt.arrow(x, y, dx*scaling, dy*scaling), fc="k", ec="k", head_width=0.06, 
head_length=0.1)

vectorized_arrow_drawing = np.vectorize(func_to_vectorize)

plt.imshow(np.flip(result_matrix,0), extent=[horizontal_min, horizontal_max, vertical_min, 
vertical_max])
vectorized_arrow_drawing(xv, yv, xd, yd, 0.1)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

This is the error I'm getting:

`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (200,335) (200,335) (100,100) (100,100) ()`

EDIT: Traceback Error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-25a8b7e2dff8> in <module>
     46 
     47 plt.imshow(np.flip(result_matrix,0), extent=[horizontal_min, 



horizontal_max, vertical_min, vertical_max])
---> 48 vectorized_arrow_drawing(xv, yv, xd, yd, 0.1)
     49 plt.colorbar()
     50 plt.show()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in __call__(self, 
*args, **kwargs)
   1970             vargs.extend([kwargs[_n] for _n in names])
   1971 
-> 1972         return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
   1973 
   1974     def _get_ufunc_and_otypes(self, func, args):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in 
_vectorize_call(self, func, args)
   2046                       for a in args]
   2047 
-> 2048             outputs = ufunc(*inputs)
   2049 
   2050             if ufunc.nout == 1:

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100,168) 
(100,168) (100,100) (100,100) ()
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback of the error, not just the last line, as that can help with diagnosing the problem

Comment: Sorry about that, I added the rest of the error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need `xd, yd, xv, yv` all to have the same shape (or all broadcastable to the same shape, but functionally that's the same thing here) for `vectorize` to work.  Easiest way to do this is:

```
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(horizontal_min, horizontal_max, data.shape[0]),
                 np.linspace(vertical_min, vertical_max, data.shape[1]))
```

The alternative if you really want more resolution in one direction than another is to use `scipy.interpolate.interp2d` to interpolate the `xd` and `yd` to the dimensions of `xv` and `yv`.  But that's a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the error occurs due to this pair of statements:

```
vectorized_arrow_drawing = np.vectorize(func_to_vectorize)
...
vectorized_arrow_drawing(xv, yv, xd, yd, 0.1)
```

Even my guess is right, you should post more of the error message.

`np.vectorize` uses `broadcasting` to combine values from the inputs, and sends a set of scalar values to `func_to_vectorize` for each combination.

According to the error, the 5 arguments have shapes:

```
(200,335) (200,335) (100,100) (100,100) ()
```

The `()` array is the scalar value 0.1.  That should be ok.  But it can't use the (200,335) arrays along with the (100,100) ones.  The `xv` and `yv` arrays are not compatible with the `xd` and `yd` ones.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense! Do you happen to have any suggestions to make them compatible? I set the horizontal  and vertical bounds to 0-100 because that is the size of the .csv image. Does that seem like the right thing to do?